# Using deleteLater() for an object with a cyclic timer

Tags: c++, qt

I create an object of a class that has a `QTimer` that runs cyclically.
The client of the program can request the removal of the task that the object is doing, which will delete the object.
When using `object->deleteLate();` the object is never deleted, but with `delete object;` it works.

Is this due to the timer field in the object running cyclically?

Comment: Can you call `emit timer.stop();` before deleting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`~QObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject) says:

> All signals to and from the object are automatically disconnected, and any pending posted events for the object are removed from the event queue. ***However, it is often safer to use `deleteLater()` rather than deleting a `QObject` subclass directly.***

Emphasis is mine. In a note later in the same document

> Warning: Deleting a `QObject` while pending events are waiting to be delivered can cause a crash. You must not delete the `QObject` directly if it exists in a different thread than the one currently executing. ***Use `deleteLater()` instead, which will cause the event loop to delete the object after all pending events have been delivered to it.***

Emphasis is mine. This means your cyclic timer, upon re-adding itself, would cause the object to always have a pending event.

If you want to use `deleteLater()`, then your cyclic timer should detect whether a `deleteLater()` is in progress, and then cancel itself if so. Then, your deletion will occur after any other pending event has been cleared.